# NPM -node-servicenow library- Proxy Support

Tags: proxy, npm, servicenow

I wanted to use node-servicenow library and wanted to check if there is any way we can pass proxy to it.Does it provide proxy support?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the library you are talking about? It isn't clear what you want to do from your question.

Comment: Hi, Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-servicenow.

Comment: I am trying to write client to use this servicenow node module to make http calls to servicenow endpoint.But since I am behind proxy, I am unable to hit the API. when I am outside the proxy, I am able to hit the API.SO my concern is how do I pass proxy to make the Rest API calls when on network where proxy is requried.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have also created a REST-Library for Service-Now in NodeJS.
To use it with a proxy just set your https_proxy environment variable.
Maybe this would also work with the library you are trying to use.

https://github.com/mak42/snrest-js